# How to send xml messages to Websphere MQ6.0 from Load Runner 11.5/ Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq, loadrunner

Can anyone please guide me how to send messages to Websphere MQ6.0 from Load runner 11.5 or from Jmeter.

Thanks in Advance,
Jephy

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=jmeter+Websphere+MQ

Answer (score 0):

In LoadRunner you have many many options for this

- JMS virtual user support in Web Services Virtual User
- JMS support in Java Template Virtual User
- MQ API support in C DLL Virtual User
- MQ API support in VB DLL Virtual User
- MQ API Support in VB Script virtual user
- MQ AQP Support in C template virtual user
- Possible use of Winsock Virtual user (demonstrable use with other MQ interfaces)